# $E=\{(x,x^2-3x+2)\in \mathbb R^2 : x\in \mathbb R\}$, $F=\{(a,a+2)\in \mathbb R^2 : a\in R\}$. What is $E\cap F$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

$$E=\{(x,x^2-3x+2)\in \mathbb R^2 : x\in \mathbb R\}\\F=\{(a,a+2)\in \mathbb R^2 : a\in R\}$$ What is $E\cap F$

The only one I can think of is $\{(0,2)\}$

Comment: $(4,6)$ is another point and there are only two points in the intersection.

Comment: How did you figure that out?

Answer (score 2):

You get $E\cap F$ by setting $x^{2}-3x+2=x+2$ which gives $x^{2}=4x$. So $x=0$ or $x=4$.  This gives $E \cap F=\{(0,2), (4,6)\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $E$ is obviously the ordered pairs $(x, f(x))$ where $f(x)$ is the given quadratic, and $F$ is obviously $(a, g(a))$ where $g(x) = x+2$.

Visibly, the common points of these sets are where $a = x$ and $(f(x) = g(x))$, or in other words, the intersection of $y = x+2$ and $y = x^2-3x+2$ This can be found by solving algaebraically or graphing, for example.

A line and a parabola may meet at at most two points unless they do not meet or they are tangent.

Here, we have $$x^2-3x+2 = x+2$$

$$x^2-4x = 0$$
$$\implies x = 0, x = 4$$
$$\implies\boxed{E\cap F \equiv \{(0,2), (4,6)\}}$$